# Javascript RegExp Tokenizing

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

Given a string, I want to use a regular expression to tokenize it.  The pattern is as follows: any character (including new line, etc.), until "<", followed by a space zero or more times, followed by "%".
I tried

```
var patt = /(.)*<(\s)*%/;
```

but it does not yield the desired result. I would appreciate an explanation along with the pattern.

Comment: Could you tell us what is it that you want to use as token separators? That way we can provide you with the regex.

Comment: `str.split(/<\s*%/)` doesn't work for you? Provide some examples and desired result.

Comment: please give sample input and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
"some string".split(/.*<\s*%/);
```

Comment: it does not work, try it for yourself on "spam beef<%more spam and beef%>spam beef".split(/(.)*<(\s)*%/); this is the pattern i used, which obviously is not correct.

Comment: I tested it in console and it's working: `"this-is+a_test".split(/[\-\+_]/) == ["this", "is", "a", "test"]`, if it's not working according to what you expect, then your regex must be the problem.

Comment: i know that the pattern is incorrect. that's the reason i posted what i am trying to achieve in words :) thank you for your help though

Comment: In JS regex, `.` does not automatically include `\n`. You should make the pattern like this: `/[.\n]*<\s*%/` or better, use the multi-line modifier: `/.*<\s*%/m`. Also, you don't need to capture stuff.

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to tokenize with? This does not make sense as token separator. Did you mean something like this: `/<\s*%/m`. This would separate "a < % b" into ["a", "b"], while yours would make it into: ["", "b"]

Comment: @MiladNaseri, `[.\n]` matches a dot or a `\n`, and `/m` does not have any effect on `.`. You were probably thinking of `/s`, but that is missing in JS. Shortest thing you can use for any char, including newline, is `[^]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[\s\S]*?< *%/
```

should do what you want.

`^` causes it to match at the beginning of the string.

`[\s\S]` matches any character.  Literally, it means any space or non-space character, and works around the fact that `.` does not match newlines.

`*?` matches zero or more but the fewest necessary for the rest of the pattern to match.

`<` matches a literal `'<`'

`*` (note the space) matches zero or more spaces.  This is more readable if written as `[ ]*`.

`%` finally matches that character.

If you want to match the entire string (i.e. the `%` should be the last character in the string), then you can put a `$` before the last `/`.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but it does not achieve what i wish, for instance `"spam beef<%more spam and beef%>spam beef".split(/^[^<]*< *%/);` the result should be `"spam beef"` or am i missing something?

Comment: your assumption is a little bit incorrect, i want any string, which can also be `"<"`, only until matching `"<"` followed by spaces (if any), and finally `"%"`. for instance, `"<spam <beef<%more spam and beef%>spam beef".split(/^[^<]*< *%/);`